# Finding userid in three column in one row

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check 3 columns in 10 row where we match userid in descending order and find a userid and display a result

Suppose this is my table

Table name **feeds**

```
id   buy_id sell_id sold_id
30     2      5       3
29     6      4       9  
28     44     21      36
27     26     2       15
26     4      2       9
25     8      7       2
24     11     2       3
23     2      1       9
```

For example: we need to find **userid 2** and set limit to 10 output.

I have work with only one column so I have no idea how i will match 3 columns in one row.

I want 10 output...

```
if userid = buy_id then echo "buyer";
if userid = sell_id then echo "seller";
if userid = sold_id then echo "third party";
```

Output should be this when we match userid 2 in column in each row:

```
1.buyer
2.seller
3.seller
4.third party
5.seller
6.buyer
```

as there is only 6 activity of userid 2 so there will be only 6 output but i need maximum 10 and minimum 0.

I have not tried any code yet as i have no clue how to deal with this.

Thanks hope i made my self clear :|

Comment: Please add your expected result. (What should the columns be?)

Comment: i have no idea what mysql_query i will run

Comment: Yes, but **what do you want the resulting table to look like?** What data do you need to be in the final results? id? userid? user type?

Comment: yes something like Barmar posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  (SELECT buy_id userid, id, 'buyer' type
   FROM feeds)
  UNION
  (SELECT sell_id userid, id, 'seller' type
   FROM feeds)
  UNION
  (SELECT sold_id userid, id, 'third party' type
   FROM feeds)
) feeds_data
WHERE feeds_data.userid = $CHOOSE_USERID
LIMIT 10
```

When you choose `2` for `$CHOOSE_USERID`, this should return a table like:

```
| userid | id |    type     |
|--------|----|-------------|
| 2      | 30 | buyer       |
| 2      | 27 | seller      |
| 2      | 26 | seller      |
| 2      | 25 | third party |
| 2      | 24 | seller      |
| 2      | 23 | buyer       |
```

You can customize the query by changing the value of `$CHOOSE_USERID` and you can drill down further by using the `id` field or `type` field using the `feeds_data` table alias.

Comment: this took me closer to what i wanted now i can added my self thanks @Aiias

Comment: well if ur are still here you can help me and tell what i need to echo?

Comment: Its giving 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 when i use id and when i use type it give 10 times buyer

Comment: @deerox - I don't understand your last comment. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,
       case when buy_id = $userid then "buyer"
            when sell_id = $userid then "seller"
            else "third party"
       end who
from feeds
where $userid in (buy_id, sell_id, sold_id)
limit 10
```